# Internal typedefs in C++ - good style or bad style?

Tags: c++, coding-style, typedef

Something I have found myself doing often lately is declaring typedefs relevant to a particular class inside that class, i.e.

```
class Lorem
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Lorem> ptr;
    typedef std::vector<Lorem::ptr>  vector;

//
// ...
//
};
```

These types are then used elsewhere in the code:

```
Lorem::vector lorems;
Lorem::ptr    lorem( new Lorem() );

lorems.push_back( lorem );
```

Reasons I like it:

- It reduces the noise introduced by the class templates, `std::vector<Lorem>` becomes `Lorem::vector`, etc.
- It serves as a statement of intent - in the example above, the Lorem class is intended to be reference counted via `boost::shared_ptr` and stored in a vector.
- It allows the implementation to change - i.e. if Lorem needed to be changed to be intrusively reference counted (via `boost::intrusive_ptr`) at a later stage then this would have minimal impact to the code.
- I think it looks 'prettier' and is arguably easier to read.

Reasons I don't like it:

- There are sometimes issues with dependencies - if you want to embed, say, a `Lorem::vector` within another class but only need (or want) to forward declare Lorem (as opposed to introducing a dependency on its header file) then you end up having to use the explicit types (e.g. `boost::shared_ptr<Lorem>` rather than `Lorem::ptr`), which is a little inconsistent.
- It may not be very common, and hence harder to understand?

I try to be objective with my coding style, so it would be good to get some other opinions on it so I can dissect my thinking a little bit.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

I think it is excellent style, and I use it myself. It is always best to limit the scope of names as much as possible, and use of classes is the best way to do this in C++. For example, the C++ Standard library makes heavy use of typedefs within classes.

Comment: That's a good point, I wonder it looking 'prettier' was my subconscious delicately pointing out that limited scope is a *good* thing. I wonder though, does the fact that the STL uses it predominately in class templates make it a subtly different usage? Is it harder to justify in a 'concrete' class?

Comment: Well the standard library is made up of templates rather than classes, but I think the justification is the same for both.

Answer (score 13):

> It serves as a statement of intent -
>   in the example above, the Lorem class
>   is intended to be reference counted
>   via boost::shared_ptr and stored in a
>   vector.

This is exactly what it does *not* do.

If I see 'Foo::Ptr' in the code, I have absolutely no idea whether it's a shared_ptr or a Foo* (STL has ::pointer typedefs that are T*, remember) or whatever. *Esp.* if it's a shared pointer, I don't provide a typedef at all, but keep the shared_ptr use explicitly in the code.

Actually, I hardly ever use typedefs outside Template Metaprogramming.

> The STL does this type of thing all the time

The STL design with concepts defined in terms of member functions and nested typedefs is a historical cul-de-sac, modern template libraries use free functions and traits classes (cf. Boost.Graph), because these do not exclude built-in types from modelling the concept and because it makes adapting types that were not designed with the given template libraries' concepts in mind easier.

Don't use the STL as a reason to make the same mistakes.

Comment: I agree with your first part, but your recent edit is a little short sighted.  Such nested types simplify the definition of trait classes, as they provide a sensible default.  Consider the new `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>` class... you don't have to specialize it for every single allocator you write, because it simply borrows the types directly from `Alloc`.

Comment: @Dennis: In C++, convenience should be on the side of the /user/ of a library, not on the side of its /author/: the user wishes a uniform interface for a trait, and only a trait class can give that, because of the reasons given above). But even as an `Alloc` author, it's not exactly harder to specialise `std::allocator_traits<>` for his new type than it is to add the needed typedefs. I've also edited the answer, because my full reply didn't fit into a comment.

Comment: But it *is* on the side of the user.  As a *user* of `allocator_traits` attempting to create a custom allocator, I don't have to bother with the fifteen members of the traits class... all I have to do is say `typedef Blah value_type;` and provide the appropriate member functions, and the default `allocator_traits` will figure out the rest.  Further, look at your example of Boost.Graph.  Yes, it makes heavy use of traits class... but the default implementation of `graph_traits<G>` simply queries `G` for its own internal typedefs.

Comment: And even the 03 standard library makes use of traits classes where appropriate... the philosophy of the library is not to operate on containers generically, but to operate on iterators.  So it provides a `iterator_traits` class so that your generic algorithms can easily query for the appropriate information.  Which, again, defaults to querying the iterator for its own information.  The long and short of it is that traits and internal typedefs are hardly mutually exclusive... they support one another.

Comment: @Dennis: `iterator_traits` became necessary because `T*` should be a model of `RandomAccessIterator`, but you can't put the required typedefs into `T*`. Once we had `iterator_traits`, the nested typedefs became redundant, and I wish they had been removed there and then. For the same reason (impossibility to add internal typedefs), `T[N]` doesn't model the STL `Sequence` concept, and you need kludges such as `std::array<T,N>`. Boost.Range shows how a modern Sequence concept can be defined that `T[N]` can model, because it doesn't require nested typedefs, nor member functions.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/range/doc/boost_range.html#minimal_interface  "Below is given an overview of which member functions *and member types* a class must specify to be useable as a certain Range concept." [emphasis mine]

Comment: The point is that Boost does exactly what I have been saying, using nested types to simplify the use of traits. Why even bother supporting Method 1 if nested types are antiquated and worthless?

Answer (score 9):

Typedefs are the ones what [policy based design and traits](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#traits) built upon in C++, so The power of Generic Programming in C++ stems from typedefs themselves.

Answer (score 8):

Typdefs are definitely are good style. And all your "reasons I like" are good and correct.

About problems you have with that. Well, forward declaration is not a holy grail. You can simply design your code to avoid multi level dependencies.

You can move typedef outside the class but Class::ptr is so much prettier then ClassPtr that I don't do this. It is like with namespaces as for me - things stay connected within the scope.

Sometimes I did

```
Trait<Loren>::ptr
Trait<Loren>::collection
Trait<Loren>::map
```

And it can be default for all domain classes and with some specialization for certain ones.

Answer (score 4):

When the typedef is used only within the class itself (i.e. is declared as private) I think its a good idea. However, for exactly the reasons you give, I would not use it if the typedef's need to be known outside the class. In that case I recommend to move them outside the class.

Answer (score 3):

The STL does this type of thing all the time - the typedefs are part of the interface for many classes in the STL.

```
reference
iterator
size_type
value_type
etc...
```

are all typedefs that are part of the interface for various STL template classes.

Comment: True, and I suspect this is where I first picked it up. It seems like these would be a little easier to justify though? I can't help but view typedefs within a class template as being more akin to variables, if you happen to think along the 'meta-programming' line.

Answer (score 3):

Another vote for this being a good idea.  I started doing this when writing a simulation that had to be efficient, both in time and space.  All of the value types had an Ptr typedef that started out as a boost shared pointer.  I then did some profiling and changed some of them to a boost intrusive pointer without having to change any of the code where these objects were used.

Note that this only works when you know where the classes are going to be used, and that all the uses have the same requirements.  I wouldn't use this in library code, for example, because you can't know when writing the library the context in which it will be used.

Answer (score 3):

Currently I'm working on code, that intensively uses these kind of typedefs. So far that is fine.

But I noticed that there are quite often iterative typedefs, the definitions are split among several classes, and you never really know what type you are dealing with. My task is to summarize the size of some complex data structures hidden behind these typedefs - so I can't rely on existing interfaces. In combination with three to six levels of nested namespaces and then it becomes confusing.

So before using them, there are some points to be considered

- Does anyone else need these typedefs? Is the class used a lot by other classes?
- Do I shorten the usage or hide the class? (In case of hiding you also could think of interfaces.)
- Are other people working with the code? How do they do it? Will they think it is easier or will they become confused?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to move those typedefs outside the class. This way, you remove direct dependency on shared pointer and vector classes and you can include them only when needed. Unless you are using those types in your class implementation, I consider they shouldn't be inner typedefs.

The reasons you like it are still matched, since they are solved by the type aliasing through typedef, not by declaring them inside your class.

Comment: That would polute the anonymous namespace with the typedefs wouldn't it?! The problem with typedef is that it hides the actual type, which can cause conflicts when included in/by multiple modules, which are hard to find/fix. It's a good practice to contain these in namespaces or inside classes.

Comment: Name conflicts and anonymous namespace polution has little to do with keeping a typename inside a class or outside. You can have a name conflict with your class, not with your typedefs. So in order to avoid name polution, use namespaces. Declare your class and the related typedefs in a namespace.

Comment: Another argument for putting the typedef inside a class is the use of templatised functions. When, say, a function receives an unknown container type (vector or list) containing an unknown string type (string or your own string-conformant variant). the only way to figure out the type of the container payload is with the typedef 'value_type' which is part of the container class definition.