# c put typedef into struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have a question about combining typedef and struct

I want to have a struct `st`, containing an `enum` `e` with elements i.e. {A,B,C}.
Later in my code, I want be able to write:

```
st.e=A;
```

One possibility is to write following code into a header file

```
typedef enum _enumDef{A,B,C} enumDef;
typedef struct _structDef{
    enumDef e;
    ...
}structDef;
```

and then in my c-file I type `structDef st` and `st.e=A`

Now my question is, can I also write something like:

```
typedef struct _structDef{
    typedef enum _enumDef{A,B,C} enumDef e;
    ...
}structDef;
```

? This one above doesn't work. But it is possible, to write

```
tyedef struct _structDef{
    enum _enumDef{A,B,C} e;
    ...
}structDef;
```

but then I could not write `st.e=A` because the enum isn't known as global argument. Instead I have to write `st.e=st.A`

So my question is, is there any possibility, to include the typedef into the struct? I think, it looks nicer and it it easier to understand, from which context the enum is from. Or this this total unusual and I should clear it from my mind :D ?
Thanks

Comment: adding to @juanchopanza's comment, are you using a c++ compiler?

Comment: sorry. i forgot typedef... I will edit it...

Comment: @iharob: no, I do not using a C++ Compiler, I use the Microchip xc32-Compiler for Microchip PIC-uC

Comment: I don't have my code in reach, but I use an enum in a struct in a C99 program I've written recently.  I made them both global, and had no problem at all (well, the usual work to be able to print the enum values, which store as integers).

Comment: Aside from the fact that typedef is apparently not allowed within a struct definition, the list "typedef enum _enumDef{A,B,C} enumDef e;" is a syntax error. Adding a comma between enumDef and e would create type types of _enumDef variables (one named enumDef and the other named e).  You cannot create the type and an instance of that type in the same statement.

Comment: ahh, ok, so when it is not allowed to use typedef within struct, so my question is solved....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any possibility, to include the typedef into the struct?

storage class specifiers is not allowed within a structure as per C standard.

So you can't have a `typedef` member within structure

Answer (score 1):

I will answer this question

> Now my question is, can I also write something like:
>
> ```
> typedef struct _structDef{
> typedef enum _enumDef{A,B,C} enumDef e;
> ... }structDef; ?
> ```

I will give you the similarity so you can see the problem

when you want to create an `int` 
 you write

```
int a,b,c;
```

so `int` is the type and `a` `b` `c` are variable

```
typedef int a,b,c;
```

Now you can create other variable with type `int` via the **tag** `a` or `b` or `c` so

```
a variable1; //is the same as ==> int variable1;
b variable2; //is the same as ==> int variable2;
c variable3; //is the same as ==> int variable3;
```

let's return to our problem when take a look at this below to see the syntax and the similarity

```
 enum _enumDef{A,B,C} e;
 |------------------| 
          |
 |------------------|
         int          e;
```

In order to create many varibales you need to add commas like in `int`

```
 enum _enumDef{A,B,C} a,b,c;
 |------------------| |----|
          |              |---->variables;
 |------------------| |----|
         int          a,b,c;
```

the problem here

```
typedef enum _enumDef{A,B,C} enumDef e;
                             |--------| 
                                   |-------> no comma (ERROR)
```

is there is no comma between the two **SAME** tags (`e` and `enumDef`) and that's why it generates the problem !!

In order to make it work just add the comma between the **same two tags** `e` and `enumDef` of structure `enum _enumDef {...}`:

```
typedef enum _enumDef{A,B,C} enumDef, e;
```

Comment: But that new typedef with the comma just creates two names for the _enumDef type.  It does NOT declare an instance of an enumDef as 'e'.

Comment: yes I just pointed that ! you cannot create an instance while using typedef in the same time defining the struct !! you will create only TAGS for the same structure !!

Answer (score 1):

If you think of the `{}` in the struct as defining a scope it tells you that everything within those brackets is local to the struct and putting a typedef in there wouldn't add much even if the C language allowed you to do it.

(Inventing a conceptual namespace implementation might give some kind of `structDef::enumDef` syntax, but that's not part of C.)

If you need to use the enumeration type outside of the struct then it should be typedef'd outside the struct.  The first example you give is the correct usage.

Comment: The `{}` don't introduce a new scope. If you declare a structure or enumeration type, they're not local to the structure.

Comment: @mafso I know.  That's why I said "think of [it] as", rather than "it is".  But thanks for clarifying the point.  My point was that (if permitted) the type would be part of the struct, as the members are, which wouldn't add very much in C if you wanted to use it anywhere other than within the context of the struct.

Comment: Strictly speaking, "if permitted" of course allows any assumption (because it just isn't permitted); but it's confusing: If you have `struct foo { struct bar *b; };` both structures are in the same scope, so it's unnecessarily complicated. For all declarations permitted inside a structure definition, their scope is the same as the structure's.

Comment: @mafso In C++ you **can** have typedefs that are private to a class and the concept of the usage in the question would be valid (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/759512/3581917)).  As you say, it just isn't permitted in C.  :-)