# Are C++-style internal typedefs possible in Cython?

Tags: python, c++, oop, cython

In C++ it's possible to declare type aliases that are members of a class or struct:

```
struct Foo
{
    // internal type alias
    typedef int DataType;

    // ...
};
```

Is there any way to do the same thing in Cython? I've tried the most obvious approach:

```
cdef struct Foo:
    ctypedef int DataType
```

But this doesn't work:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
# distutils: language=c++

cdef struct Foo:
    ctypedef int DataType
   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

internal_typedefs_example.pyx:4:4: Expected an identifier, found 'ctypedef'
```

Is this just a fundamental limitation of Cython (I'm using v0.21.2), or is there a workaround?

---

Why bother with internal typedefs? There are several general reasons - [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/759512/1461210) covers a few of them.

The specific case I'm interested in is wrapping a set of templated C++ classes that look something like this:

```
struct FooDataset
{
    typedef int DataType;
    typedef float ReturnType;

    // methods, other important stuff
};

struct BarDataset
{
    typedef long DataType;
    typedef double ReturnType;

    // methods, other important stuff
};

template <class Dataset>
class DataProcessor{

    DataProcessor(Dataset& input_data);

    typedef typename Dataset::DataType T;
    typedef typename Dataset::ReturnType R;

    T getDataItem();
    R computeSomething(); /* etc. */

    // do some other stuff that might involve T and/or R
};
```

Having typedef(s) internal to the struct gives me better encapsulation since I only need to pass a single template parameter (the `Dataset` class) rather than individually specifying the `Dataset` plus `T, R, ...` specific to that `Dataset` type.

I realise that it's not too difficult to find workarounds for this case - I'm mostly just interested in getting a definitive answer as to whether or not internal typedefs are currently possible in Cython.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not currently supported in Cython. But can't you just define it outside of the struct?

Cython is not currently designed as a replacement for C++, rather a way to speed up hot spots in python code. If you need something more involved just write it in C++ and expose python bindings.

Comment: There are a bunch of reasons why internal typedefs can be a good idea - [see here for some examples](http://stackoverflow.com/q/759512/1461210). I'll add some more information to my question regarding my specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, [`struct` is a keyword to declare a class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class).  Thus, the internal `typedef` can be declared in Cython as:

```
cdef cppclass Foo:
    ctypedef int DataType
```