# Is it valid to place a typedef inside a class that uses class itself as template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, typedef

Are there any pitfalls of putting a typedef inside a class if the typedef uses the class it is in as a parameter?

```
#include <memory>


class Foo{
  public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Foo> shared_ptr;
}


void main(){
  Foo x;
  Foo::shared_ptr p = std::make_shared<Foo>();
}
```

The above code works for me (clang) but I was wondering if the standard had anything to say about it.

Comment: Yes, this is legal. C++ compilation is not done in a single pass. There's nothing wrong with using a type that has not yet been fully defined in a declaration. You see the same thing in the [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp). But since you're looking for specifically what the standard has to say about this, I've added the [[tag:language-lawyer]] tag.

Comment: What advantage do you see here ?

Comment: @SidS It puts the `shared_ptr` typedef inside `Foo`'s scope and can be accessed through `Foo::shared_ptr`. If the typedef was outside of `Foo`, I would have to be careful about remembering what class `shared_ptr` was a pointer for or do `Foo_shared_ptr`, which is ugly.

Comment: How is `Foo::shared_ptr` better than `shared_ptr<Foo>` ?  The former could mean anything, while the latter has only one meaning.

Comment: @SidS I think that issue has to do with why I should typedef in the first place. Given that I do want to typedef, it makes sense to limit its scope to `Foo`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/759512/5101335) discusses better than I could the pros and cons of internal typedefs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `typedef` inside the `Foo` class is a **declaration** and **not a definition** so it is allowed to do what you are doing. If it were a definition it would not be allowed because the definition of the `Foo` class is not complete until the closing brace.

> 6.1 Declarations and definitions [[basic.def]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def)
>
> 2 A declaration is a definition **unless**
> ...
>
> [(2.9)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def#2.9) — it is a `typedef` declaration (10.1.3),

But if you did something like this:

```
class Foo{
  public:
    Foo f; //A definition
}
```

`Foo f` will be considered a definition and the [compiler will issue an error](https://godbolt.org/z/IB4g0G) like:

> ```
> error: field has incomplete type 'Foo'
>     Foo f;
>         ^
> <source>:1:7: note: definition of 'Foo' is not complete until the closing '}'
> class Foo{
> ```